# Getting old file name in filerenamed event

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using C Sharp.Net fileSystemWatcher class to watch if file renamed. Code is working fine and giving notification if file renamed but I am unable to find out old name of renamed file. I am using 'e.OldFullPath' but it's not working. 
I am getting error: does not contain definition for oldFullPath

My code:

```
private void watcher_FileRenamed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("File " + e.OldFullPath + " [Changed to] " + e.FullPath);
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because you're not changing directory, but just name.
So try to use `e.OldName` for old name and `e.Name` for new name and see what happens.

`e.OldFullPath` is used for other operations like copying or moving.

Comment: Thanks, by changing directory it's working fine. I've changed directory to System.IO.RenamedEventArgs

Comment: @SmartBoy: if my answer helped you you could upvote and/or [accept](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=stackoverflow%20accept%20answer&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5234%2Fhow-does-accepting-an-answer-work&ei=GR2hTsPxGo_EsgaHv9nkAg&usg=AFQjCNFydg7FnTBZP4nXWXx2wWflwYQ80A) it. Thanks